# Parse not working on mobile after updating

Tags: parsing, unity-game-engine

I have made a project in Unity, which saves user data on parse.com.

It works well in the Unity editor and has also worked well for months, building and running on iOS device.

So yesterday I updated Unity to 5.6.0f3.

Since then, it is no longer working on my mobile.

So I also made these updates, to try to solve the issue:

macOS Sierra version 10.12.4.

Xcode 8.3.1.

Parse SDK from this link:
https://docs.back4app.com/docs/parse-migration/parse-sdk/how-to-update-parse-sdk-for-unity/

iPhone to iOS version 10.3.1.

So now it still only works in Unity editor.

Meaning I can save and query the database from the Unity editor on my macbook, but when I build to my iphone, it is not working to save or query on my iphone :(

Any advice ??

Ola